# Excel: Runtime Error 13 for DateAdd one column to another column

Tags: vba, excel, dateadd

**New to coding-- please bear with me!**

I'm trying to create an event procedure for a date add that starts when workbook open and when a worksheet change happens.

A "Closeout" date is manually input in range F3:F50 by the user. In turn, I want another date to automatically insert into range D3:D50 that is 60 days sooner.

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.EventProc1 Sheet1.Range("D3:D50")
End Sub
```

^^My understanding: kicks off the event proc for sheet1 for the specified range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    EventProc1 Me.Range("D3:D50")
End Sub
```

^^Does the same thing when sheet is opened.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    EventProc1 Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F3:F50"))

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

^^This is where it starts to get confusing. I made the Intersect F3:F50 thinking that I want a Worksheet Change to happen when it detects new data being input in F3:F50 (which in turn should affect D3:D50).

```
Sub EventProc1(rng As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Closeout As Date

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        Closeout = Range("F3:F50").Value
            Select Case cell
                Case Date: Cells.Value = DateAdd("d", -60, Closeout)
                Case Else: Cells.ClearContents
            End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

^^My attempt at the main code. I was tweaking it part by part to try to get it to work until my debugger started to give me a Type Mismatch error for the string "Closeout = Range("F3:F50").Value" and my novice skills are stumped.

Any suggestions? The reason I have this set up as an EventProc is because I will have more EventProcs on top of it. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should get you a bit closer to where you need to go:

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Should probably provide a better check for datatype as well here
    'but your previous code had several cells assigned to the date
        If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F3:F50")) Is Nothing Then
        Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        EventProc1 Target

        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End If
    End Sub


    Sub EventProc1(rng As Range)
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim Closeout As Date
            Closeout = CDate(rng.Value) 
        Cells(4, rng.Column).Value = DateAdd("d", -60, Closeout)

    End Sub
```

Edit:  Okay, just call this event whenever you want.  It should roll through each cell and update it accordingly and every time.  :-)

```
Sub NewEventProc1()
    Dim rngCell as Range
    For Each rngCell in Range("F3:F50")
        If TypeName(rngCell) <> "String" Then
             Cells(4, rngCell.Column).Value = DateAdd("d", -60, rngCell.Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I still get the same mismatch error after "Closeout = rng.Value"

And this is from the debug starting from Workbook_Open and going directly to the Sub EventProc1.

Comment: Give it a try with the CDate function.  For this to work with multiple cells, you will need to run through each cell with a For Each pattern

Comment: CDate doesn't change anything. A regular Excel formula is what I had originally-- I just wanted to create a macro so that the user didn't accidentally change the formula.

Comment: Use whatever event you need to trigger the newevent.  I think this should wrap you up.